# wxpython's wxEvent.Skip() explained

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm recently learning `wxPython` via `wxPython in Action`, but I got stuck in Chapter 3, especially to the explanation of `Figure 3.3`'s `Skip()` diamond

In `Step 3 Locating the binder object`, the book writes:

> If a binder isn't found for the object itself, the processing walks up
>   the class hierarchy to find a binder defined in a superclass of the
>   object--**(1)this is different than the walk up in the container hierarchy
>   that happens in the next step.**

But in the next step, `Step 4 Determining whether to continue processing` writes:

> The event handler asks for more processing by calling the wx.Event
>   method Skip(). If the Skip() method is called, processing continues
>   and **(2)any** handlers defined in the **(3)superclass** are found and executed in
>   the step. The Skip() method can be called at any point in the handler.
>   The Skip() method sets a flag in the event instance, which wxPython
>   checks after the handler method is complete. In listing 3.3 the
>   OnButtonClick() doesn't call Skip(), so in that case the event process
>   is complete at the end of the handler method. The other two event
>   handlers do call Skip() **(4)so the system will keep searching for a
>   matching event binding**, **(5)eventually invoking the default functionality
>   for mouse enter and leave events for the native widget, such as
>   mouse-over events.**

My questions are related to numbers I marked in the passage:

(1) In my understanding and some other googled materials, *propagat* is something happens in the container hierarchy, **NOT** the class hierarchy, is this correct?

(2) Seriously? **any** handlers are executed? not the ones matching the instance and event combination?

(3) Is **superclass** here correct? shouldn't it be **parent windows?**

(4) I think this line contradicts with question2, so maybe not **any** handlers are executed, just the ones which match the instance and event combination?

(5) What is a `default functionality`? and how is it invoked?

If anyone is intersted, listing-3.3.py is here:

```
import wx


class MouseEventFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, 'Mouse Events',
                          size=(300, 200))
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.button = wx.Button(self.panel,
                                label='Not Over', pos=(100, 15))
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnButtonClick, self.button)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnEnterWindow)
        self.button.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW, self.OnLeaveWindow)

    def OnButtonClick(self, event):
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour('Green')
        self.panel.Refresh()

    def OnEnterWindow(self, event):
        self.button.SetLabel('Over Me!')
        event.Skip()

    def OnLeaveWindow(self, event):
        self.button.SetLabel('Not Over')
        event.Skip()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MouseEventFrame(parent=None, id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: wxWidgets is nice in many ways but this wxEvent::Skip() name is very poorly thought out. It is the single most confusing function name IMHO in the entire wxWidgets library.

Comment: It is better IMHO to rename wxEvent::Skip() as wxEvent::TreatAsUnhandled().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When an event associated with some object is generated, the order of the handler lookup is:

1. [wxApp::FilterEvent()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.0/classwx_app_console.html#ada7ab606e014a10d46e4b3c6f602e20c)
2. Any event handlers [pushed on](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0.0/classwx_window.html#a398c11ab9af7956067a964f560d1978c) the object itself. I am not even sure if this is exposed in wxPython, and in any case this shouldn't be used any more.
3. The object itself, starting from the handlers registered in the most derived classes and continuing with the handlers defined in the base classes.
4. If the event is "propagatable" (which is the case by default for `wxCommandEvent` but not, say, `wxMouseEvent`) and if the object is a window, then all the parent windows of the object, recursively.
5. `wxTheApp` itself.
6. And finally, the default handler for the event at the underlying toolkit level is used. What, if anything, it does, depends on the exact event kind and the platform but for some events it's very important to let it be called, notably for the focus events you must let the default native control handlers get them in order to update their focused state.

Now, what about `Skip()`? Normally, the first handler found while searching is used and the event processing stops there. However if the handler calls `event.Skip()` during its execution, *this event handler* is skipped and the search continues. I.e. the important thing to understand is that `Skip()` doesn't skip the event, even though it's called on the event object. Instead, it skips the event handler calling it.

Hopefully you understand now why is it important to call `event.Skip()` in `wxFocusEvent` handlers.

Comment: Actually I'm confused about after skipping this handler, where does wxpython find the next one? via the class hierarchy? or the container hierarchy?

Comment: Skipping the handler means that the search doesn't stop but continues in the order of the list above. So the "next one" depends on the "current one". If you call `Skip()` in a handler found on step 3, the search continues with further base classes. If you do it in a handler found on step 4, it continues with the further parent windows.

Comment: Oh, does it mean if I have `BaseButton(wx.Button)` and `DerivedButton(BaseButton)`, then if a handler is found in `DerivedButton` and I called `Skip()` in it, the handler in `BaseButton` would be the next to run. And if there isn't a handler in `BaseButton`, `wxPython` would try to find a handler in `wx.Button`, if there is still no handler, then the `container window` will be searched for handlers? Am I right?

Comment: Am I right to understand that event.Skip() acts as return ? Or what would "However if the handler calls event.Skip() during its execution, this event handler is _skipped_ and the search continues" mean ?

Comment: I can't add much to what the [documentation](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_event.html#a98eb20b76106f9a933c2eb3ee119f66c) already says.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D `event.Skip()` actually sets a flag. The skip occurs only at the end of the handler code. It is then that the flag is checked. If the flag is set to `True` (default when `Skip()` is used), then the search occurs.